# How to replace ID in the path that appears in a string using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**Example**

```
$string = "This is the paragraph which also contains link http://example.com/document/EN010001-0001, now this is some text after the link";
```

Considering above example, where link can appear anywhere in the string, I would like to replace this `EN010001-0001` with different ID, e.g. `EN010003-0001`.

I know we can use `preg_replace`, can someone please help with the correct regular expression for this scenario?

**Edit #1**

Link `http://example.com/document/` is static and it appears as it is in the string.

**Edit #2**

```
   preg_replace("http://example.com/document/([-\w]+)", 'EN010003-0001', $string);
```

I tried this but was given warning:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

Comment: are links guaranteed to be http/s, or will relative paths be allowed?

Comment: link http://example.com/document is static as it is.

Comment: Please provide some more input strings, at the moment, you could even come up with sth. as simple as `document/([-\w]+)` but this is certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?<=http://example\.com/document/)[-\w]+~', 'EN010003-0001', $string);
//=> This is the paragraph which also contains link http://example.com/document/EN010003-0001, now this is some text after the link
```

Another alternative is to use `\K` (match reset):

```
$str = preg_replace('~http://example\.com/document/\K[-\w]+~', 'EN010003-0001', $string);
```

Comment: This worked - great, would this replace all occurrences?

Comment: Yes it will replace all the occurrences

Comment: Can you suggest best resource you think for learning reg expressions please?

Answer (score 1):

If your string at the beginning is always the same, you could come up with the following regex (using `preg_replace_callback()` for the inner logic):

```
$string = "This is the paragraph which also contains link http://example.com/document/EN010001-0001, now this is some text after the link";
$replacements = array("EN010001-0001" => "EN010003-0001");
$regex = '~/document/([-\w]+)~';
$string = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function($match) use ($replacements) {
        return $replacements[$match[1]];
    },
$string);
echo $string;
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/zO0lN7/1). Obviously, you will need to check if the match/key really is in the `$replacements` array.